# How to reform the Density Functions to make logical predictions in this problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I would like your opinion on the following problem which I'm trying to tackle.

A boat's radio can be heard from a distance and depending on this distance, the noise of the sensed signal varies. Let's assume that given a noise, the probability that the viewer lies at a specific distance to the boat can be described by the following [Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution):

$p(d|n) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{d^{2}e^{-\frac{d^{2}}{2n^{2}}}}{n^{3}}$, where d≥0

Let's assume now that a receiver detects 2 signals (from 2 independent boats). A signal with noise 1500 and a signal with noise 8000. These two [corresponding PDFs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foaop.png) suggest that the receiver should be around 2500 meters from the first boat and 12km from the second boat.

Taking each of the functions above and replacing $d$ with $\sqrt{(x-cx)^{2}+(y-cy)^{2}}$ (from the circle equation), I guess we get a new $f(x,y)$ function, where, given a CenterPoint[$cx, cy$], the PDF is now rotated about the Z-axis of the CenterPoint (like a "solid of revolution"). For example, assuming that I had a prior belief that the first boat was at the CenterPoint$[cx=30000,cy=30000]$ and the second boat was at the CenterPoint$[cx=15000,cy=15000]$, then the above PDF's would lead to [these two revolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgoTy.png).

Although I have a belief regarding the position of each boat, I have no idea of where the receiver is. Therefore, I thought of finding where the product of these functions becomes maximum, to infer that the receiver is most probably at that point.

*Update:
I would like to mention that in this example, I am using only 2 boats. However, I might have signals from $n$ boats and thus, need to maximise the product of n functions.

With that said, my question is.. do I have first to normalize each f(x,y) function so that the volume beneath it is 1? I ask because [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c277T.png) where the only difference between the two (top-left) PDF's is their location (and thus, $P_{A}(5)=P_{B}(10)$), yet, a rotation of them (which would lead to the bottom functions) would produce different normalization constants and so, I guess.. $P_{A}(0,5)≠P_{B}(0,10)$.

What are your thoughts/suggestions/corrections?

Thx for your time, if I had some reputation here I would place some bounty too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find $(x,y)$ that maximizes the product

$$p(\sqrt{(x-x_A)^2 + (y -y_A)^2} \mid n_A) \times p(\sqrt{(x-x_B)^2 + (y-y_B)^2} \mid n_B)$$

then normalizing would not matter at all. I mean it literally would not change the result, i.e. the optimal $(x,y)$, because

$${p(\sqrt{(x-x_A)^2 + (y -y_A)^2} \mid n_A) \over K_A} \times {p(\sqrt{(x-x_B)^2 + (y-y_B)^2} \mid n_B) \over K_B}$$

has the same argmax $(x,y)$ regardless of the normalizing constants $K_A, K_B$.

There might be other ways of estimating $(x,y)$ where normalizing would change the result, but not when you're just maximizing the product of the densities (a sort of max-likelihood estimator).

Comment: I did not mention (but, I updated my post with this info), but in fact I have n functions (due to n boats) to consider. And not only 2. In that case, the $n$ normalizing constants would still not affect the result?

Comment: I don't think they would.  Imagine you're optimizing e.g. $f(x,y) g(x,y)$ vs ${f(x,y) \over 5}{g(x,y) \over 3} = {f(x,y) g(x,y) \over 15}$.  Wouldn't the optimal $(x,y)$ be the same, and the optimal values just differ by a factor of $1/15$?  Clearly this extends to another $h(x,y)$ etc.